# itertools ifilter and islice function and generators

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the significance of itertools.ifilter() and itertools.islice() functions to get a sense of what generators are all about.

```
import itertools

def is_even(x):
    print('is_even called for {}'.format(x))
    return (x%2 == 0)

def even():
    return filter(is_even,range(20))

def even_ex():
    return itertools.ifilter(is_even,range(20))
    #return filter(is_even,range(20))

unlazy_even = even()[:4]
lazy_even = even_ex()
first_four = itertools.islice(lazy_even,0,4)
print('unlazy even {} lazy even {}'.format(unlazy_even,lazy_even))
for item in first_four:
    print(item)
```

The problem is I would really like to use python 3.5.  But the function itertools.ifilter is not present in python 3.5. Also filter returns a `filter object` instead of a list in python 3.5.  How do I convert the above program to Python 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3.0, the 2.x `filter` function that returned a list was replaced by `itertools.ifilter`, which returns an iterator.  So replace `itertools.ifilter` with `filter`.  I believe this is one of the substitutions done by the 2to3 converters program.  To keep `even` non-lazy, replace `filter(...)` with `list(filter(...))`.  This is another 2to3 substitution.